# How can I list custom post type categories of portfolio

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

this code below lists wordpress categories and works

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select Category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0&selected=6');
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
echo $select;
?>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="View" /></noscript>
</form>
```

But I have a custom post type called portfolio and I want to list all categories of portfolio in the same way can anyone help?

Comment: This should be fairly easy. On the function `wp_dropdown_categories()`, you just have to add another parameter `taxonomy`. like - `wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=portfolio_cat')`. You have to figure out the name of portfolio category taxonomy and replace with `portfolio_cat`.

Comment: thankyou for your response but unfortunatly it doesn list any category I just tried like this : wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=portfolio&show_option_none=Select Category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0&selected=6');

Comment: If your Custom post type name is "portfolio", the same won't be for the taxonomy name. You just have to figure-out the name. Visit the WP Admin Portfolio Categories page, and look at the url where it says `&taxonomy=`.

Comment: I used this tutorial here http://jasonskinner.me/2013/03/creating-a-wordpress-photo-gallery-using-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function: `wp_list_categories();`. You can find more information on [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).

Here is how to display the list:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'taxonomy'    => 'portfolio_taxonomy', // your custom post type Taxonomy
    'order'       => 'ASC' // Order of the list
);

wp_list_categories($args); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but now its not visible more so maybe something missed in functions.php?

Comment: `<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'    => 'portfolio', // your custom post type Taxonomy
    'order'       => 'ASC' // Order of the list
);
$select = wp_list_categories($args);
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
echo $select;
?>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the whole piece of code but if you want to display a list of your CPT taxonomy just use the code above. You need to have a custom taxonomy registered for this Custom Post Type though using `register_taxonomy();` function (in your functions.php). Here is [more information about this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Comment: Yes register_taxonomy() is ok but I dont know why it doesnt list anything I have posts in portfolio and a portfolio page I just want to list the categories of portfolio as design,broscures etc.

Comment: What's the name of your `portfolio` taxonomy? You need to put the taxonomy name in the `'taxonomy' =>` argument instead of custom post type name.

Comment: Anyway thankyou for your help and time spent I changed idea registered a menu in functions.php as portfoliomenu and used http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/mini-dropdown-menu/demo it has a better look and I can add menus from admin menus I think this solution is better